# sed command to append some lines

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

I want append some lines through a bash script with sed. The script works but the output is wrong.

```
LINEB="word"
sed '/g id=\"..\"/a style=\"fill:$LINEB;\"' file.txt > foo.txt
```

I get `<g id="ai" style="fill:$LINEB;">` instead of `<g id="ai" style="fill:word;">`

Even if I use all kinds of parenthesis.

Comment: It's not substituion. It's append `/a`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't embed a variable inside single-quotes.  You could:

1. use double-quotes around the entire sed script, and backslash-escape all the double-quotes inside it.
2. end the single-quoted string with a `'`, double-quote-the variable, and then re-start the single-quoted string again:

```sh
LINEB="word"
sed '/g id=\"..\"/a style=\"fill:'"$LINEB"';\"' file.txt > foo.txt
```

Comment: Yeah but I get this error `sed: -e expression #1, char 66: extra characters after command`

Comment: That would be because your sed command is invalid.  I'm unable to fix that because i have no idea what you're trying to do with sed.  The technique for switching between single and double-quotes will work even better with a valid sed command.  Also remember that your variables have to be properly escaped if they are to be successfully embedded in a sed command.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to take care that `$LINEB` is properly prepared for a `sed` `a`ppend command:

```
sed '/<\([^"<>]*\("[^"]*"\)* \)*g id="[^"][^"]"/a\'"$(echo;#"'
     printf 'style="fill:"%s"\n' "$LINEB" |
     sed 'H;1h;$!d;s/\\/&&/g;s/\n/\\&/g')
"    <infile >outfile
```

It might also be easier to locate the `a`ppended text in another file that you can then `r`ead in whenever appropriate:

```
printf 'style="fill:%s"\n' "$LINEB" >/tmp/LINEB
sed '/<\([^"<>]*\("[^"]*"\)* \)*g id="[^"][^"]"/r /tmp/LINEB' <infile >outfile
rm /tmp/LINEB
```

This requires no escaping.